# Android: Height of EditText widget

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to make an `EditText` smaller in height than the default `wrap_content` height.

Reducing the layout height property doesn't work. Reducing the text size property doesn't work. Reducing the padding doesn't work. All these attempts have produced horrible visual effects.

Does anyone please know how to do this successfully ?

Comment: what layout your using for your edittext?and is there any other widget in that row ,if there is give both of them the same height

Comment: All these attempts have produced horrible visual effects.

Comment: to reduce height of editText you need to change in layout is :: android:layout_height="20dp"  here you can set height in number

Comment: @scorpio: "Reducing the layout height property doesn't work."

Comment: fisrt here update your main.xml

Comment: @joel you should post your xml code here so that we can look into the matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible unless recreating the ui pictures.